# How to get records with top dates in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Account table and a StatementSummary table.

The StatementSummary table holds data for statements sent out every month for every account. But sometimes, for some reason, statements don't go out to the account holders.

I need a list of accounts where:

1. The statement has not gone out for at least 6 months
2. The Outstanding balance is at least $1000

**My code:**

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,StatementDate
      --,MAX(StatementDate)
      ,AmountDue
      ,InvoiceNumber


FROM [StatementSummary] S
INNER JOIN Account A ON S.AccountID = A.AccountId

WHERE AmountDue >= 1000
  AND StatementDate <= '2017-02-10'  --Should be (sysdate-180)

--GROUP BY A.AccountNumber, StatementDate

ORDER BY StatementDate DESC
```

This code gives me a list of accounts and their data for the statement period before 6 months ago. But these accounts have data for later statements as well.

I need accounts who have NOT received any statements since 6 months ago at least.

---

---

**EDIT:** ****
The only fields used from the Account Table are
 1. AccountId
 2) AccountNumber

The fields in the StatementSummary Table used are
 1. AccountId
 2. InvoiceNumber
 3. StatementDate
 4. NewCharges
 5. AmountDue

A Statement is generated every month and every month, new charges are incurred on that account.

I need the details form the LAST Statement where:

1) the last StatementDate is before 6 months ago and
 2) where the AmountDue is more at least $1000

**Sample Data:**

```
AccountNumber   StatementDate AmountDue InvoiceNumber
32563696        2017-07-16      1259.05 2279250276
32563696        2017-06-16      1043.00 2273976792
32563696        2017-05-16       974.00 2273976651
32067247        2017-07-01      5385.84 2277258801
32067247        2017-06-01      4218.71 2271971177
32067247        2017-05-01      2977.56 2276955130
32067247        2017-04-01      1518.85 2274063149
31279191        2017-06-01    214746.49 2271930486
31279191        2017-05-01    184178.38 2276913639
31279191        2017-04-01    141984.13 2274025518
31279191        2017-03-01    110914.52 2270228069
31279191        2017-02-01     76083.25 2257406893
31279191        2017-01-01     45997.75 2253462824
```

**What I really need:**

```
AccountNumber     StatementDate AmountDue     InvoiceNumber
11201057          2017-02-01    9114.29       2255223280
11201147          2017-02-01    1189.52       2255223235
11203824          2017-02-01    8984.36       2255223819
11206052          2017-01-01    2274.54       2255223381
11206298          2017-01-01    5792.11       2255223358
11208852          2016-12-01    2175.62       2255223987
11209202          2016-12-01    1199.58       2255223976
11209246          2016-12-01    1017.12       2255256003
11209268          2016-11-01    1775.32       2255256025
```

---

---

**So, in plain words:**
I need a list of accounts and their data ONLY where the LAST statement sent for more than 6 months ago and also ONLY WHERE the AmountDue is $1000 or more.

Comment: Use NOT EXIST or NOT IN

Comment: your second data set doesn't reflect your sample data.

Comment: 'Sample' data. Can't post real data on here. Too sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it, based off what you have posted. Though sample data would help.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT A.AccountNumber
          ,StatementDate
          --,MAX(StatementDate)
          ,AmountDue
          ,InvoiceNumber
          ,row_number() over (partition by A.AccountNumber order by StatementDate desc) as RN
    FROM [StatementSummary] S
    INNER JOIN Account A ON S.AccountID = A.AccountId
    WHERE
        s.AccountID in (select AccountID from StatementSummary group by AccountID having Max(StatementDate) < dateadd(day,-180,getdate()))
        and s.AmountDue >= 1000)

select
    AccountNumber
    ,StatementDate
    ,AmountDue
    ,InvoiceNumber
from CTE
where
    RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but this code didn't work. It gave me records for each account number and all of their statements. I only needed the LAST statement for each account number and ONLY those where NO statement was sent after 6 months ago. Thanks for your attempt anyway. I have edited my question with more info.

Comment: It does give you only the ones that haven't had a statement in the past 6 months. i'll ad a quick edit to get you only the last....see the edit @user1777929

Comment: Your edited code, above, gave data from last month as well. Then I added a minus sign before 180 (-180). That gave me accurate data. Thank you, very much.

Comment: Sorry that was a type o

Comment: Just guessing, but I would think the `AmountDate >= 1000` should be outside of the `cte` in the final `select`. If the most recent statement from 6 months ago was less than 1000, but the one 7 months ago was over 1000, then this would return that older statement. Not sure if that is desired or not.

Comment: Thank you, SqlZim and scsimon. I had mentioned clearly, that they had to be where last statement sent was 6 months ago at least AND AmountDue was at least $1000.____ Anyway, my results show a minimum of $1000. No records with accounts owing less than $1000. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

using `not exists()`:

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,S.StatementDate
      ,AmountDue
      ,InvoiceNumber
FROM [StatementSummary] S
INNER JOIN Account A ON S.AccountID = A.AccountId
WHERE AmountDue >= 1000
  and not exists (
    select 1 
    from [StatementSummary] i
    where i.AccountId = a.AccountId
      and i.StatementDate > dateadd(month,-6,getdate())
      /* other option based on comment */  
      and i.StatementDate > dateadd(day,-180,getdate())
    )
ORDER BY StatementDate DESC
```

---

`inner join` option to get the latest statement for an account when no statement has been sent within the last 6 months:

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,S.StatementDate
      ,AmountDue
      ,InvoiceNumber
FROM [StatementSummary] S
  INNER JOIN Account A 
    ON S.AccountID = A.AccountId
  inner join (
    select 
        AccountId
      , MaxStatementDate = max(StatementDate)
    from StatementSummary i
    group by i.AccountId
    having max(StatementDate) <= dateadd(month,-6,getdate())
    ) x on s.AccountId = x.AccountId 
       and s.StatementDate = x.MaxStatementDate
WHERE AmountDue >= 1000
ORDER BY StatementDate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, but this query gives me a list of accounts with the last statement  sent 6 months ago AND ALSO previous statements, hence resulting in multiple AmountDue figures.____ I need only the LAST Statement: Eg TOP 1  ORDER BY StatementDate DESC

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,StatementDate
      --,MAX(StatementDate)
      ,AmountDue
      ,InvoiceNumber

FROM [StatementSummary] S
INNER JOIN Account A ON S.AccountID = A.AccountId

WHERE A.AmountDue >= 1000
  AND S.StatementDate <= '2017-02-10'
```

--Maybe both tables have same columns' name?

Comment: The only common column name is AccountId.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to get your 6 months case records:

```
Select * From [StatementSummary]
Where datediff(DAY, GETDATE(), StatementDate) Between -180 AND -1
```

Comment: Thank you, but this query will give me all statements from 6 months earlier. _____I only needed the LAST statement for each account number and ONLY those where NO statement was sent after 6 months ago. Thanks for your attempt anyway. I have edited my question with more info.

Comment: Play around "Between -180 AND -1" you can get any forward or preview ranges. like Between 1 AND 180.